# How to differenciate instanciated variables from others?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
        Piece grille[][] = new Piece[9][9];
        grille[0][0] = new Piece(1,joueur1,0);
        grille[8][0] = new Piece(1,joueur2,0);
        grille[0][8] = new Piece(1,joueur2,0);
        grille[8][8] = new Piece(1,joueur1,0);
        grille[0][1] = new Piece(3,joueur2,1);
        grille[1][0] = new Piece(3,joueur2,1);
        grille[1][1] = new Piece(3,joueur2,1);
        grille[7][0] = new Piece(3,joueur1,2);
        grille[7][1] = new Piece(3,joueur1,2);
        grille[8][1] = new Piece(3,joueur1,2);
        grille[7][7] = new Piece(3,joueur2,3);
        grille[7][8] = new Piece(3,joueur2,3);
        grille[8][7] = new Piece(3,joueur2,3);
        grille[0][7] = new Piece(3,joueur1,4);
        grille[1][7] = new Piece(3,joueur1,4);
        grille[1][8] = new Piece(3,joueur1,4);
        grille[3][4] = new Piece(2,joueur1,0);
        grille[5][4] = new Piece(2,joueur2,0);

        for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                if(grille[i][j].joueur == null)
                    grille[i][j] = new Piece(0, null,0); //0 correspond a case vide
            }
        }
```

My instance variables in Piece are :

```
public int type;    
public Joueur joueur;
public int param;
```

It seems that the error comes from this: `grille[i][j].joueur == null`

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Citadella.(Citadella.java:35) at Partie.main(Partie.java:8)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Which error? Where's the stacktrace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Citadella.<init>(Citadella.java:35)
 at Partie.main(Partie.java:8)

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you're assigning all the places before making a blind call. It'd probably be an NPE on the.joueur.

Comment: You're trying to access `.joueur` from a null object.  You should instead check `if (grille[i][j] == null)` before checking if a property of it is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `if grille[i][j] == null` instead of dereferencing joueur on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you have empty spots in your array. The loops are going to make blind calls, `grille[0][0].joule` then `grille[0][1].joule` then `grille[0][2]`. Since you didn't assign `grille[0][2]` it's null. Thus your null pointer exception.